# Do the libraries of the Arduino Uno work with the Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I did a project with the Arduino Due and the libraries for the VS1053 MP3 Shield were not compatable with the Due. Are the libraries that work with the Uno compatable with the Arduino Mega?

Answer (score 2):

> Are the libraries that work with the Uno compatable with the Arduino Mega?

Sometimes.

They have a higher chance of being compatible, due to them both using the same AVR core, but since internal peripherals differ slightly there is a chance that, depending on what the library does, it won't work right.

You just have to try it and see.

Comment: The main question is: Is that shield compatible with Arduino Mega as SPI is not located on pins 10-12?

Comment: @KIIV Do you know the answer to that question?

Comment: If it's [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12660) then I would suspect that yes it is. Pins 11 to 13 are linked directly to the SPI header (note: this means you can't use pins 11-13 for other things on the Due/Mega).